# What is the phenomenon of devaluing others' abilities called?

Tags: bias

The Dunning-Kruger describes a cognitive bias where people evaluate their own skills as greater than reality.

I wonder about a similar situation wherein one underestimates the abilities of others. I would tend to think this occurs when the other individual is either highly-skilled or more skilled than the one making judgement, but I'm not sure that is absolutely necessary.

Is this a known phenomenon? If so, what are the motives?

Comment: fundamental attribution error